# ReportViewer control loading indicator?

Tags: .net, reportviewer

Is it possible to change the image (the green spinning thing) of the ReportViewer control?

At the moment I am hiding it and overlapping a progress bar (this is WinForms not the ASP Control)... Seems a bit long winded?

Thanks **:)**

Comment: Haha yeah! I'm using DevExpress WinForm stuff... got a slick black theme going on with this silly (pixelated) green thing in the middle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you gave me a challenge with this one my friend.  But I figured out how to do this.  Here is the code that I used to pull this off:

```
 Private Sub CustomizeRV(ByVal ctrl As Control)
    For Each c As Control In ctrl.Controls

      If TypeOf c Is PictureBox Then
        Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(c, PictureBox)
        pb.Image = YOURNEWIMAGEHERE
      End If

      If c.HasChildren Then
        CustomizeRV(c)
      End If
    Next
  End Sub
```

Call this function during your form load event, and it will reconfigure the loading image to whatever you specify (pass the function the ReportViewer control).  The function is called recursively until the picturebox is found.  There is only one picturebox in the ReportViewer control, so you don't have to worry about finding that specific one.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked great. I have converted your code to C# for the project this is for (ill include it as an answer so it can be formatted) - but thanks! I dont see why they never had this as an option in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks again to Jon for the original VB.NET code... Here is his answer in C#...

```
private void CustomizeReportViewer(Control reportViewer)
{
    foreach (Control c in reportViewer.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
        {
            (c as PictureBox).ImageLocation = "C:\\Loading.gif";
            return;
        }

        if (c.HasChildren)
            CustomizeReportViewer(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For those bummed that this is for WinForms and not ASP.NET, this is the same solution for web:

```
Private Sub CustomizeRV(ByVal ctrl As Control)
    For Each c As Control In ctrl.Controls
        If String.Compare(c.ID, "AsyncWait")=0 Then
            DirectCast(c.Controls(0).Controls(0), Image).ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/images/PleaseWait.gif")
        End If

        If c.HasControls Then CustomizeRV(c)

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a ton for sharing this question.Just converted the above vb.net code to c#.net and changed the image backaground color.

```
private void CustomizeRV(Control ReportViewCntr)
{
    foreach (Control c in ReportViewCntr.Controls)
       {            
          if ((string.Compare(c.ID, "AsyncWait") == 0))
          {   
            Image i = (Image)c.Controls[0].Controls[0];
            i.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Images/loading.gif");
            //i.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray; 
            i.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e6e6e6");
           }
          if (c.HasControls())
          {
            CustomizeRV(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code sample to replace the image control in the AsyncWait. This was working absolutely fine till I upgrade my report viewer control to the latest version i.e. version 15.0.0.0.

After the upgrade the control at the position "c.Controls[0].Controls[0]" as in the code sample from @Pratik is no more an image control. Hence, it throws an error saying cannot convert LiteralControl to image.

I tried using above code with some minor edits as below:

```
 protected void CustomizeRV(Control ReportViewCntr)
    {
        foreach (Control c in ReportViewCntr.Controls)
        {
            if ((string.Compare(c.ID, "AsyncWait") == 0))
            {
                c.Controls[0].Controls.RemoveAt(0);                    
                Image i = new Image();
                i.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/images/loading.gif");
                //i.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray; 
                i.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e6e6e6");
                c.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, i);
            }
            if (c.HasControls())
            {
                CustomizeRV(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it didn't work as expected.

Is there any other way we can replace the new literal control with the gif image?