# Changing the Progress bar "Loading..." message in the SSRS Reports after clicking "View Report" button

Tags: reportviewer, reporting-services

I want to change the "loading..." Message while report is loading say "Report is loading, Please Wait This will take few seconds..." like. Any way to change this?.

Note: I am not using any ASP.NET Application. I need this to be done in SSRS.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way I did this in ASP.NET Application is Implementing the IReportViewerMessages.

Changing the ProgressText Property

```
string IReportViewerMessages.ProgressText
        {
            get
            {
                return ("Please Wait... This will take some time");
            }
        }
```

Other properties are Just Returning null. That inturn takes the base values explained in the link below.

```
string IReportViewerMessages.BackButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
```

Edit web.config and add Appsetting Tag

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ReportViewerMessages" value="MyNamespace.MyRVMessageClass, MyAssembly" />
</appSettings>
```

the below link is helpful in how to do this and explains what it is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages(v=vs.80).aspx

Still looking ahead how to do it in BIDS SSRS.

Comment: I think i could'nt explain my problem. I don' t want to change Progress message or hide back button. I want to hide LOADING GIF.

Answer (score 1):

I think we cannot change the loading message in SSRS. Its only the get property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages.progresstext.aspx

The above link is the reason why I am telling we cannot change.

We can change this message in the ASP.NET Application that I had done with the javascript code.

To change spinningWheel loading Indicator the solution is we have to go for windows or web application as @Harri link says.

To change the message I used the ASP.NET Application. Now it is changed when the parameters are refreshed after selecting. Still in some places I have to change.

**Source after browsing:**

```
<div id="ReportViewerDisplay_AsyncWait_Wait" style="cursor:wait;background-color:#DC9CE4;padding:15px;border:1px solid black;display:none;position:absolute;">
        <table height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="32px" height="32px">
                    <img src="/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=10.0.30319.1&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SpinningWheel.gif" style="height:32px;width:32px;"/>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
                    <span style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:14pt;">Loading...</span>

                    <div style="margin-top:3px;">
                        <a href="javascript:$get(&#39;ReportViewerDisplay_AsyncWait&#39;).control._cancelCurrentPostback();" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;color:#3366CC;">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**ASP Design Page:**
 
         function get(arg) {

```
         var divTag = document.getElementsByName('ReportViewerDisplay_AsyncWait_Wait');
            if (divTag != null ) {
                var tableTag = divTag.item(0);
                var rowTag = tableTag.childNodes[0];
                var columnTag = rowTag.childNodes[0];
                var tdtag = columnTag.childNodes[0];
                var spantag = tdtag.childNodes[0].nextSibling.childNodes[0];
                spantag.outerText = arg;
            }
     };
  </script>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void ReportViewerDisplay_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "PrintScript_" + UniqueID, "get('Please Wait');", true);
        }
```

Note: ReportViewerDisplay is the Id of the ReportViewer control change accordingly

If you agree with this mark this answer as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is an image (gif), so you need to create an image with custom message in it. For the implementation I think you should see this question: [ReportViewer control loading indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919895/reportviewer-control-loading-indicator).

Comment: This method is called in the form load event as I mentioned I am not using any ASP.Net Application. How to do the same in the SSRS.

Comment: If SpinningWheel.gif is the one you are speaking about it is an indicator but not the message that it shows.

Comment: I am afraid you are right.May I ask you the way you are viewing a report in your web page? And in what cases the Loading message is showing? I mean, are you using drillthrough reporting, multiple parameters in your report or what other scenarios that need showing this message.

Comment: I am viewing my report by deploying the reports into the report server and browsing with the URL. It doesn't matter what kind of report I am viewing its common for all the reports that are viewing in the report viewer. Eventhough I have multiple parameters and drillthrough in my report for your information. When all the report parameters are given and clicked the View Report button. Then report will fetch the data and render the data this scenario it will occur.

Comment: I was thinking about hiding the original message and showing something else instead of changing it.

Comment: Check this question: [Want to show Custom wait control at center of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377305/want-to-show-custom-wait-control-at-center-of-page).

Comment: I Don't have ASP.NET Application for checking this. I am working on the reporting services project that are deployed in the report server there we cannot write the jquery. I got your idea of supressing the Image by different image. Any idea on how to do this in report server will be helpful.